# QNAP Web UI - How to get the windows in a web app?

Tags: user-interface, web, nas, qnap

I am learning to write web apps. I am currently working on a project and recently purchased a QNAP Nas unit. The web UI for the admin settings is perfect for what I would like, but I don't know how to do the windows thing. 
Basically you have a menu on the left of the web UI and when you select an admin option it opens a window that you can move around and minimize etc within the app. Does anyone know what technology this is? I don't mind RTFM but I jsut need to know what to read. I have googled and cannot find anything on whatever it is, probably because I don't know what to google for.

Something like this:

[image: QNAP Admin]

If anyone can point me in the right direction of what I can google or read up on that would be great.

Comment: Hey did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: @reach4thelasers
I never did, but I think I found something. It looks like they maybe use JQueryUI
See this link for an example
[link](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

If the link doesn't work google for JQueryUI Draggable

I found YTCracker.com and used wget to see how it was done there, he uses something very similar, if not exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

You need JavaScript application framework for building interactive cross platform web applications using techniques such as Ajax, DHTML and DOM scripting.
QNAP is using [extJS](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/).

[Web Desktop demo](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/examples/classic/desktop/index.html) using extJS that you were looking for.